# CoreMotion crash: CLMotion core, CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

```
Application crashes when CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type notification is received. Cmmotionmanager object would be listening to notification.
```

< Crash log:
        Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
        Crashed Thread:  0

```
//Thread 0 crash onGeomagneticModelNotification
    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37cf6edc objc_retain + 12
    1   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x35eb1aca _Block_object_assign + 114
    2   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x35eb1212 _Block_call_copy_helper + 18
    3   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x35eb19b0 _Block_copy_internal + 172
    4   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x35eb1ae2 _Block_object_assign + 138
    5   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x35eb1212 _Block_call_copy_helper + 18
    6   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x35eb19b0 _Block_copy_internal + 172
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x30aa626a CFRunLoopPerformBlock + 410
    8   CoreMotion                      0x32404648 CLMotionCore::executeBlockOnMotionThread(void ( block_pointer)()) + 124
    9   CoreMotion                      0x323f122a onGeomagneticModelNotification(int, CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::Notification const&, CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::NotificationData const&, void*) + 74
    10  CoreMotion                      0x3242887a CLNotifier<CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::Notification, CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::NotificationData, char, char>::invokeClientWithData(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, CLNotifier<CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::Notification, CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::NotificationData, char, char>::Client> > const&, std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::Notification const, CLNotifier<CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::Notification, CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::NotificationData, char, char>::Notification> > const&, CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::NotificationData const&) + 134
    11  CoreMotion                      0x324289ec CLNotifier<CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::Notification, CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::NotificationData, char, char>::invokeClientsWithData(CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::Notification const&, CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::NotificationData const&) + 348
    12  CoreMotion                      0x32429f96 CLNotifier<CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::Notification, CLGeomagneticModelProvider_Type::NotificationData, char, char>::onDpcSource(void*) + 186
```

>

Comment: Do you have some more information? Did you try debugging...

Answer (score 0):

I had met with the same question, finally, I found the cause is 
    CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical

you can try other CMAttitudeReferenceFrame s.

I guess this behavior is the bug of CoreMotion framework.